# How to make two ul li elements inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this ul element in my page:

```
            <ul class="nav pull-left" style="width: 90px; list-style-type: none;margin: 0; padding: 0;">             
                <li><a href="#" style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br> sites</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br> events</a></li>         
            </ul>
```

Here how it looks:

[image]

I need to change the appearance above and to make both elements inline:

[image]

I tried this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal). But I didn't get desired result. How can I make to elements inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the "display:inline-block" style applied to the `<A>` tag, instead of the `<LI>` tag. Switch it over to the LI tag and it should look correct for you.

Also, you should probably try to avoid putting styles directly on tags like this, and instead use an attached stylesheet. Imagine you had to change 30 of these, that'd be a huge pain. If you had a stylesheet, you'd only have to change one small line.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I remove highlighting when I navigate mouse to anchor tag in li?

Comment: If I understand your question, it seems like you'd want to add a line to your file like so: <style>ul.nav li a:hover{text-decoration:none}</style> Please note again, however, that this should definitely all be placed in an attached stylesheet, rather than directly in the HTML itself. You can try adding it directly into the HTML though to test it out and see if that solves your question

Comment: Here I posted a question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922487/how-to-remove-highlighting-on-anchor-element

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `display:inline-flex` in `<ul>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav pull-left" style="width: 90px; list-style-type: none;margin: 0; padding: 0;display:inline-flex;">
  <li><a href="#" style="text-align: center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br> sites</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-align: center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br> events</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see this question is marked as [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).  It appears you are trying to use the built in `.nav` class, but you're also trying to align it left.  You're also missing a class to make `.nav` work.  It takes two parts to define a bootstrap nav (e.g. `nav nav-navbar`, `nav nav-pills`).  I would recommend using `.nav-pills`.  That will make the `pull-left` unnecessary and you can remove it.  You should also remove those inline styles.  To center the glyphicon, just use `.text-center` or create a custom style.  Please, do not inline styles.

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css)
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">             
  <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i><br>sites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i><br>events</a></li>         
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this code . for viewing glyphicon we must add bootstrap , and thats why i have added background color and width, height property set as a demo , copy paste this to a html page

```css
.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:47%;
    background:#999;
}
.nav li i {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav pull-left" style="width: 90px; list-style-type: none;margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i>sites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i>events</a></li>
</ul>
```