# How to remove highlighting on anchor element?

Tags: html, css

I have this html elements anchors generated in `<ul>` element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav pull-left">             
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sites.list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br>sites</a></li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> <br>events</a></li>         
</ul>
```

When I navigate mouse on the links it highlighted.

Any idea how can I remove highlight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of Bootstrap's CSS rules is :

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Simply override it with your own, more specific rule:

```
.nav.pull-left>li>a:focus, .nav.pull-left>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Example:

```css
.nav.pull-left>li>a:focus,
.nav.pull-left>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav pull-left">
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sites.list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br>sites</a>
  </li>
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> <br>events</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add some custom CSS to overwrite the bootstrap styles.

```css
.nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav pull-left">             
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sites.list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br>sites</a></li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> <br>events</a></li>         
</ul>
```

***Note** If you include your custom styles after your bootstrap CSS, there is not need for `!important`. Or if you prefer, you could create a more specific selector like in j08691's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your custom css file

```
ul.nav.pull-left a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is issue is because of bootstrap css.

```
    .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    a:focus, a:hover {
        color: #23527c;
        text-decoration: underline;
   }
```

You can simply solve this issue by adding some css.

```
a {
   color: #337ab7;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
.nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #337ab7;
 }
```

By giving color property the hover color change will be removed.

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use css hierarchy.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav pull-left">             
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sites.list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br>sites</a></li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><a class="" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> <br>events</a></li>         
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.nav>li>a:focus, ul.nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rLxnczdp/

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because bootstrap already has their styles set. You can override their styles with your own.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```